# Rails Beginner Attempting TDD:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, tdd, specifications

I'm new to unit testing and Rails in general.  I've decided to build my projects in a TDD environment, but this has left me with some early questions.
I need help building the models to pass this test:

```
describe User do
  it "should add user to team" do
    team = Team.create(:name => "Tigers")
    akash = User.create(:name => "Akash")
    akash.teams << team
    akash.memberships.size.should == 1
  end
  it "should allow buddyup"
    john = User.create(:name => "John")
    john.buddyup_with(akash)
    john.memberships.size.should == 1
  end
  it "should validate linked buddys"
    akash.buddys.should include(john)
  end
end
```

Basically, ALL I want to do right now is pass the tests.  Here is what I have so far:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  attr_accessubke :name

  validates :name, :presence = true
                   :uniqueness => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many: :teams
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, :presence = true
                   :uniqueness => true 
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end

class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :teams
  end
end

class CreateTeamsUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :teams_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :team_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :teams_users
  end
end
```

That is all I have so far, and clearly it is nowhere near completion.  Could you provide some insight, and perhaps code I should use to complete this?  My biggest problem right now is the buddyup_with part.  Adding a buddy will add a person to every team you are a member of, think of teams as parts of a development company, and buddys as understudies or something.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions I would make:

1. Use `before do
    # code #
   end`

   to set up your conditions.
2. Do 1 test per. You have a lot going on there :)
3. Use Factory Girl.
4. Try what you have and work from there (Agile approach, even to adding tests).

Comment: his question is: write the necessary code to make my test pass. I deleted my own answer to avoid doing someone else's homework.

Comment: Actually @apneadiving, I'm a professional Objective-C developer with no TDD experience.  I picked up a RoR book last week and I'm trying to learn the intricacies in my free time through what I'll admit is a brute-force manner.

Comment: As you and @apneadiving suggested, I've cut the test code above into three sections.  Hopefully this makes the model-building a little simpler for me.  :)

Comment: The real issue I have is in implementing the buddyup portion.  I'm not quite sure how this kind of linking would work.

Comment: I've added a users/teams join table.